# How to give path in Linux to read data from a file in Java

Tags: java, linux

I have a java class like below which reads data from properties file,

java class and properties file both are same directory

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("MyProp.properties");
```

Then it is compiled success fully and created war file.
This war file i deployed in server, then running properly in windows

Same war file i deployed in another server in Linux, then it is giving exception as

```
FileNotFoundException
```

Comment: Please show your windows deployment and then your linux deployment. I'm interested in the files in the current working directory and the files in the war.

Comment: I suspect it is a current working directory issue. You may want to specify a full path to the file for the Linux version.

Comment: modify it to FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("./MyProp.properties"); and let us know.

Comment: Ensure your file name matches as Linux is case sensitive while Windows isn't.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is outside your war, I recommend using a fully qualified path instead of just a relative path.  If you need to run in both Windows and Unix-y environments, first detect the operating system like so:

```
System.getProperty("os.name");
```

Then set the path accordingly.

However, if the file is in your war, just read it from the classpath like so:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("MyProp.properties")
```

or:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/MyProp.properties");
```

See this for more details: [How to really read text file from classpath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java)